# QT Creator C++ and run time lib

Tags: c++, qt, installation

I'm planing for making setup file in qt creator for some proposes , any way my questions
  Dose the release exe required any run-time lib ?

Regareds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dynamic link your app, it will need some libraries (if you are developing on Windows, use Dependency Walker to identify all of them).

Also, take a look at the Qt modules your app need to compile: each of them corresponds to a library, which you will need to bundle with your app.

If you are static linking, I believe you may need a smaller number of libraries (those that are not bundled with Qt), but will still need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "static linkage is only allowed for the Comercial License of Qt." In a word: **no**. See [LGPL 2.1, sec 6a](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html): " if the work is an executable linked with the Library, with the complete machine-readable "work that uses the Library", as object code and/or source code, so that the user can modify the Library and then relink to produce a modified executable containing the modified Library."